# Is there a United States waterbody index number available?

Tags: united-states, rivers, waterways, lakes

In searching for this, I see that in some countries they have a waterbody index number, a unique ID for each water body.

Does such a system exist in the US and is it available online or from any government agencies? My online searches have yielded nothing.

Comment: I think this may be a question more suitable for the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: I think the USGS hydrologic unit codes are as close as you will get.

Comment: Christopher, I agree, you should put that as an answer and link to this what is HUC page: https://nas.er.usgs.gov/hucs.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

USGS hydrologic unit codes are the US standard IDs in the United States. 
More on HUCs here: https://nas.er.usgs.gov/hucs.aspx

NOTE: This does not mean your state or local government uses these in their data.